# Registering a Nib

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I would like to set the values of detail labels in the View Controller file using an array with index path.row .

In a previous post:
[link][1]

someone helpfully suggested I use

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "YourCellSubclass", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

however I'm new to using this and came across an error:

```
Cannot invoke registerNib with an argument list of type 'UINib, forCellReuseIdentifier: 'String'
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be, instead of this:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
```

Should be:

```
var cell: YourSubClass = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as YourSubClass
```

---

This compiles in Xcode 7:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCellSubclass

    return cell
}
```

If you have multiple kinds of cells, you can go with:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let aCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if let myCell = aCell as? MyCellSubclass {

        return myCell
    }

    return aCell
}
```

Comment: This just returns an error of 'Undeclared type 'My Subclass'

Comment: @RuiAAPerez This seems to function but then I receive the error: Cannot invoke dequeue reusable cell with identifier with an argument list of type string

Comment: Also, could you please take a look at the other errors? Thanks!

Comment: try using `table`, instead of `self.table`. Others have stated that in another question.

Comment: No change...Maybe the errors have something to do with the Nib bundle